# Object code parentheses (beginner)

Tags: python, object-code

Why do I have to add the () at the end of f in this example?

```
def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

def print_spam():
    print 'spam'

do_twice(print_spam)
spam
spam
```

Is it because function objects require a specified argument for functions?

Comment: When you add parentheses to the end of a function name it means you are calling it. If you don't do so, the function simply won't be called.

Comment: I think.... because f will just refer to the object while f() will execute the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Why do I have to add the () at the end of f in this example?

Because `f` is the function, and `f()` actually *calls* the function. In your example `do_twice(print_spam)` sends the `do_twice` function the actual `print_spam` function, not its result. If you would have used `do_twice(print_spam())`, the `do_twice` function would have received `print_spam`'s return value, which is `None`

Answer (score 0):

This is a language decision, python does require all function calls to have `()` to make things unambiguous. Take these few examples,

```
 a = b
```

If b was a function, it would be ambiguous what `a` would gets (the b function object or the result of calling b?).

```
 a( b )
```

what would `a` receive? (the b function or the result of calling b?). By requiring `()`, these problems do not arise